# How to create key for nested submenu?

Tags: reactjs, recursion, menu, key

I have little problem because "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." but I cant create unique key for components.
I try add random key but then I have multiple error message becuase is key not equal.

In this place is create sublink in menu and submenu

```
function NavBarLink({ ...props }) {
  const [classOpener, setClassOpener] = useState(false);
  const arrow = <i className="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>;
  const arrowDown = <i className="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>;
  const pathToCategories = `/categories/${props.codename}`;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleTaxonomies(codename) {
    dispatch(catchCodeNameTaxonomies(codename));
    setClassOpener(!classOpener);
    return codename;
  }

  return (
    <span
      className={`opener ${classOpener ? "active" : ""}`}
      key={Math.floor(Math.random())}
    >
      <Link
        className="d-flex justify-content-between"
        to={pathToCategories}
        onClick={() => handleTaxonomies(props.codename)}
      >
        <span>
          {props.name}
        </span>
        <span>
          {props.showArrow ? (classOpener ? arrow : arrowDown) : ""}
        </span>
      </Link>
    </span>
  );
}
```

In this component is created submenu

```
function NavBarItem({ ...props }) {
  function generateLink() {
    return (
      <NavBarLink
        name={props.name}
        codename={props.codename}
        showArrow={props.terms && props.terms.length > 0}
      />
    );
  }
  function generateSubmenu() {
    return <Menu items={props.terms} key={Math.floor(Math.random() * props.terms.length)} />;
  }
  function generateContent() {
    const content = [generateLink()];
    if (props.terms) {
      content.push(generateSubmenu());
    }
    return content;
  }
  const content = generateContent();
  return (
    <li> {content}</li>
  );
}
```

Main components to export where is start taxonomies

```
export default function Menu({ ...props }) {
  function generateItem(item, index) {
    return (
      <NavBarItem
        key={index}
        name={item.name}
        terms={item.terms}
        codename={item.codename}
        onClick={props.handleId}
      />
    );
  }

  const items = props.items.map((item, index) => generateItem(item, index+1));
  return <ul className="menu-ul-child">{items}</ul>;
}
```

```
index.js:1375 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `NavBarItem`
    in NavBarLink (at TaxonomiesMenu.js:44)
    in NavBarItem (at TaxonomiesMenu.js:69)
    in ul (at TaxonomiesMenu.js:80)
    in Menu (at Sidebar.js:75)
    in nav (at Navbar.js:6)
    in Navbar (at Sidebar.js:66)
    in div (at Sidebar.js:48)
    in div (at Sidebar.js:47)
    in Sidebar (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at App.js:44)
    in div (at App.js:42)
    in Route (at App.js:64)
    in Switch (at App.js:63)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:62)
    in App (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at src/index.js:10)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:9)
```

Comment: In `NavBarItem`, have you tried just using the name prop as a key for each `<NavBarLink>`? `<NavBarLink key={props.name}>` (assuming the name is different for each item.)

Comment: don't use index for keys. Use some item.id or something more universally unique.

Comment: key={props.name + props.codename} I must use bebacuse some taxonomies is equal and I add in Menu  key={props.codename + props.name}. But this purpose is usefull :-) thank you Arno!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of existing npm packages like `uuid` or `uniqid` to generate random unique keys

```
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');
const uniqid = require('uniqid');

uuidv1(); // ⇨ '2c5ea4c0-4067-11e9-8bad-9b1deb4d3b7d'
console.log(uniqid()); // -> 4n5pxq24kpiob12og9
console.log(uniqid(), uniqid())
```

[Example from the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Comment: or you can use Math.random().toString(32) but it can be bad choice because these keys won't be saved and every rerender will change keys

Answer (score 1):

For every menu elements **just use item name or title or href as keys** because

1. it's unique
2. it's not index
3. it's not changeable after re-render

Comment: How sure are we that the title/name of an item will be unique?

Comment: in the best way you should have unique title or text or href and they can be good choice,